# GWT Deserialize Generics List in RPC Call

Tags: java, gwt, rpc, gwt-rpc, deserialization

I have a method that returns a list of serializable objects, I make an RPC call to this method and everything went well until the deserialization process: I received the following message: "The response could not be deserialized"

Note: Here is my gwt-rpc response string:

```
 / / OK [0,2768,3,2,0,2764,3,2,0,2761,3,2,0,2754,3,2,0,2750 , 3,2,0,2610,3,2,0,2606,3,2,0,2603,3,2,0,2600,3,2,9,1 ["java.util.ArrayList/3821976829 "" myPackage.MyEntity/845101117 "," java.lang.Integer/3438268394 "], 0.7]
```

DTO

```
public class MyEntity implements Serializable,IsSerializable
{
   private static final long serialVersionUID = -9032157988566853424L;

   public MyEntity ()
   {
      super();
   }

   private Integer _entityId; 


   private String _name;

   public Integer getEntityId()
   {
      return _entityId;
   }

   public void setEntityId(Integer entityId)
   {
      this._entityId = entityId;
   }

   public String getName()
   {
      return _name;
   }

   public void setName(String _name)
   {
      this._name = _name;
   }

}
```

Interfaces

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("ContributorService.rpc")
public interface ContributorService extends RemoteService
{
   ArrayList<MyEntity> myMethod(Arg arg);
}
```

---

```
public interface ContributorServiceAsync
    {

       void myMethod(Arg arg, AsyncCallback<ArrayList<MyEntity>> callback);

    }
```

Server Implementation:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ContributorServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements ContributorService
{

   @Override
   public ArrayList<MyEntity> myMethod(Arg arg)
   {
      ArrayList<MyEntity> myList = new ArrayList<MyEntity>();
MyEntity myEntity=new MyEntity();
      //code...
myList .add(myEntity);
      return myList;
   }
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: I have never seen implements Serializable,IsSerializable on a class before usually just one is enough. I use Serializable and that always works for me.

Comment: I have used only serializable but it did not work.

Comment: I think my problem is with the list because when I edit the method to return an object instead of list everything work well.

Comment: Which GWT version are you using? There was a bug in GWT < 1.5 around a very similar (the same?) problem: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=1985

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to everyone for the help
it was a stupid mistake that I still can not understand.
I changed GWT sdk and the program worked, then I used the old SDK to ensure that the problem emanates from the sdk but the surprise the program still works ':(

I understand nothing of what is past but the more important that my application works :)